# Is it possible to write to the crontab from a multipurpose script?

Tags: shell-script, cron

When I want to manipulate Unix cron, I do

```
crontab -e
```

then type (or paste) my directives.

How do I paste directive to crontab **directly from a script**?

In other words: Instead of pasting content inside crontab -e, I want to paste and save it there from outside, ready from a script, so to automate things up.

I ask this regarding a multi-purpose script I run each time I create a new VPS environment (for example, new Digital Ocean droplet).

---

I can type to **files** via, for example:

```
sudo bash -c "touch /location/new_file && echo 'text...text...text...text' > /location/new_file
```

**Or:**

```
sudo cat <<EOF >> /location/new_file
text...
text...
text...
text...
EOF
```

Yet, I don't know if it is even possible to write directly to Crontab from a script, and how.

This is the task I would want to paste inside Cron tab --- From a script:

```
0 8 * * *  tar -zcvf /home/USER/backups/files/www-html-$(date +\%F-\%T-).tar.gz /var/www/html
0 8 * * *  find /home/USER/backups/files/* -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;

0 8 * * *  mysqldump -u benia -p121212 --all-databases > /home/USER/backups/mysql/alldb_backup.sql
1 8 * * *  tar -zcvf /home/USER/backups/mysql/alldb_backup-$(date +\%F-\%T-).sql.tar.gz /home/USER/backups/mysql/alldb_backup.sql
2 8 * * *  rm /home/USER/backups/mysql/alldb_backup.sql
2 8 * * *  find /home/USER/backups/mysql/* -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;
```

### Note:

The above cron task does 2 things:

1. Daily backup all site-dirs and all sqls, into 2 different dirs: One is ~/backups/files and one is ~/backups/sql
2. Find and delete files created 30 days ago --- each day anew.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate (and as the answers demonstrate, the manual page should be your first resource).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per Ipor Sircer's answer about the usage of `cron`, i.e.

> man crontab:
>
> ```
>    crontab [ -u user ] file
>
>    The  first  form  of this command is used to install a new crontab from
>    some named file or standard  input  if  the  pseudo-filename  ``-''  is
>    given.
> ```

this means that you send the **lines** you want in your crontab file, to the stdin of this command:

```
crontab -
```

`crontab` will recreate a new cron file containing those commands.

1. The script will first print your existing crontab using `crontab -u $user -l 2>/dev/null`.
   <sub>you will need to assign the value of your user to `$user` or use `$USER` if its in your environment.</sub>
2. It will print the new lines you want and capture the aggregated result into a pipe connected to stdin of `crontab -`.

---

Here's how it should look like in your general-purpose script:

```
#!/bin/bash

user=YOU_NEED_TO_ENTER_YOUR_USER_HERE

# use a subshell to capture both commands output into the pipe (    # prints the current value of crontab
    crontab -u $user -l 2>/dev/null

    # print your cron jobs to STDOUT    
    cat <<- 'EOF'
        0 8 * * *  tar -zcvf /home/USERNAME/backups/files/www-html-$(date +\%F-\%T-).tar.gz /var/www/html
        0 8 * * *  find /home/USERNAME/backups/files/* -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;

        0 8 * * *  mysqldump -u benia -p121212 --all-databases > /home/USERNAME/backups/mysql/alldb_backup.sql
        1 8 * * *  tar -zcvf /home/USERNAME/backups/mysql/alldb_backup-$(date +\%F-\%T-).sql.tar.gz /home/USERNAME/backups/mysql/alldb_backup.sql
        2 8 * * *  rm /home/USERNAME/backups/mysql/alldb_backup.sql
        2 8 * * *  find /home/USERNAME/backups/mysql/* -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;
    EOF

# Everything printed to stdout - inside the subshell will be connected
# to the pipe and feed to crontab on stdin - recreating a new crontab ) | crontab -
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more on user=YOU_NEED_TO_ENTER_YOUR_USER_HERE ? I guess you mean to "su USERNAME" for in case I logged in as root, I will now switch-user via su USERNAME? Thx.

Comment: @Benia oh ok, its the name of the user which owns the crontab. I'm guessing thats probably you anyway? if it its just use your username e.g. make the line look like this `user=Benia` or what ever your UNIX user name is.

Comment: Yes I log in as my one single non-root user always... It's only me in that server.

Comment: @Benia ok well I would recommend taking a backup of your  current crontab, update the script as per my comment above and try the script.

Comment: Gave you a thumb up. Please allow me to know 1 more thing from you: Why do need to do crontab -u $user -l 2>/dev/null instead of just crontab -l, if all of our aim is to print the current users' crontab? I mean, why do we need to pick a certain user and also redirect the output to the null device? Sorry if this question sounds funny, I'm quite new to Unix.

Comment: @Benia good question. you are right, for you specifying the user was unnecessary as the Unix user  running the command was the same user who owned the crontab. but I didnt know that when I made the script. so by explicitly specifying the user you would be sure to target the correct crontab user in case you ran the command under another account. e.g. root. I didnt redirect output to null, only the error. 2 means std error

Comment: Is the hyphen in cat <<- 'EOF', uses for arguments? I ask because in some other examples I saw it was only cat << 'EOF', without the hyphen. Thanks!!!!!!

Comment: @Benia the hyphen means bash will ignore leading tabs in the heredoc. without the hyphen the text in your cronjob would be indented. see man bash " heredoc" for more info

Answer (score 1):

man crontab:

```
   crontab [ -u user ] file

   The  first  form  of this command is used to install a new crontab from
   some named file or standard  input  if  the  pseudo-filename  ``-''  is
   given.
```